# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.3.0'

Tags: android

There are some problems with my build.gradle file of my Android Studio Project, I'm unable to resolve it.
Whenever i build project following errors occur:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.3.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.3.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.3.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Here's dependecies section of my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.3.0'

    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${androidSupportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${androidSupportLibraryVersion}"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'


    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2.2'
}
```

project level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Comment: allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
} did you added this in root gradle file

Comment: yes already did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner:hydra-sdk-android:2.3.0'`

instead of

`implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.3.0'`

[link](https://jitpack.io/#AnchorFreePartner/hydra-sdk-android/2.3.0)

Comment: tried uisng these, but non of them is working: 
implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:sdk:2.0.0' 
implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner:hydra-sdk-android:2.3.0' 
implementation 'com.github.AnchorFreePartner.hydra-sdk-android:hydra:2.3.0'

Comment: have you tried this steps `file -> invalidate caches/Restart` Then select `invalidate and restart`